# VSCode adding a single space to my auto-indents

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-code

For the last day, whenever I make a new line, VSCode adds a single space to the auto-indent. Currently my auto indent with spaces is 4 but it adds a space at the end to make it 5. I'm not sure what caused it as I was in the middle of coding something when it suddenly started happening and its been happening ever since for every new line
Normally with an auto indent of 4 spaces if you were to define a function it would look like

```
def function1(self):
    return x
```

But for some reason it has been adding exactly one space to most indents to make it look like

```
def function1(self):
     return x
```

with an extra space before `return`. It's been doing this for basically any indents (def function indents, loop indents, etc) and I don't know how to fix this. I am opening code from Github desktop app onto vscode if that is helpful. Any solutions?

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: @starball Thanks, I figured out which extension was causing it

Comment: which extension was causing it? https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: do any of these issue tickets explain this behaviour you're seeing? https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4341, https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4071

Comment: Describe your steps in detail and show your settings.         Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).